# How can i reset the discount count on my code?

Tags: python

How can i reset the "Discount" count? as you can see at "price of toy 2", the discount is displayed as "discount 3, 4 and 5" how can i reset this count and display "discount 1, 2, and 3" at "price of toy 2" thank you for your help

```
count = "yes"
discount = 0
x = 1
y = 1
toyAmount = 1

while x <= toyAmount:
    if count == "yes":
        toyPrice = int(input("Price of Toy " + str(x) + " = Rp."))

        while True:
            toyDiscount = int(input("Discount #" + str(y) + ": "))
            if toyDiscount != 0:
                y = y + 1
            else:
                break

        count = input("More Toys? (yes/no) = ")
        x += 1
        discount += 1
        toyAmount += 1

    else:
        break
```

```
**Output:**
Price of Toy 1 = Rp.20000
Discount #1: 40
Discount #2: 30
Discount #3: 0

More Toys? (yes/no) = yes
Price of Toy 2 = Rp.30000
Discount #3: 20
Discount #4: 50
Discount #5: 0

More Toys? (yes/no) = no
```

Comment: Thank you for both answer <3, both solution works perfectly <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `y = 1` at the end of the code -

```
count = "yes"
discount = 0
x = 1
y = 1
toyAmount = 1

while x <= toyAmount:
    if count == "yes":
        toyPrice = int(input("Price of Toy " + str(x) + " = Rp."))

        while True:
            toyDiscount = int(input("Discount #" + str(y) + ": "))
            if toyDiscount != 0:
                y = y + 1
            else:
                break

        count = input("More Toys? (yes/no) = ")
        x += 1
        discount += 1
        toyAmount += 1
        y = 1 # Add it here, so that discount starts from one

    else:
        break
```

Result:

```
Price of Toy 1 = Rp.50
Discount #1: 2
Discount #2: 0
More Toys? (yes/no) = yes
Price of Toy 2 = Rp.20
Discount #1: 1
Discount #2: 0
More Toys? (yes/no) = no
```